# How to programmatically trigger/click on a MenuItem in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have these menu items in my `menu_main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_restart" android:title="Restart"
        android:orderInCategory="1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_clear" android:title="Clear"
        android:orderInCategory="2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_update" android:title="Update"
        android:orderInCategory="3" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_about" android:title="About"
        android:orderInCategory="4" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_try_restart" android:title="Try Restart"
        android:orderInCategory="5" />
</menu>
```

And I have this in my `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_restart) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Restart...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_clear) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clear...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_update) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Update...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "About...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_try_restart) {
        // how to click / trigger the "action_restart" from here?
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have tried with:

```
MenuItem actionRestart = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_restart);
actionRestart; //
```

But `actionRestart` reference doesn't offer anything like `click`, `trigger`, etc.

I'd also like to note that I'm new to Android development and I come from PHP/JavaScript background, so this level of Java OOP is all new to me.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the method `performIdentifierAction`, like this:

```java
menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.action_restart, 0);
```

Comment: How can I get the [menu] from activity's [onCreate]?

Comment: @p2lem8dev, you can get the menu in public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: exactly what I need

Comment: This is actually works for me ,Thank you .

Comment: Great! :) It's also work for NavigationView Menu and MenuItem. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You should manually call your listener, with required item as parameter.

```
MenuItem actionRestart = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_restart);
onOptionsItemSelected(actionRestart);
```

Comment: I will try this too! I've made a separate method, as I have described in Veselin Romic's answer up above. Thank you too.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem

Comment: In my case it throws exception when I try to find the view in [onCreate] method. How can I get there?

Comment: the method findViewById() returns null in onCreate() method. Where the code should be put?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, there is no mechanism in the SDK that lets you do this. It's certainly not standard practice to do this sort of thing.

I recommend decoupling your logic from the actual UI as much as possible, so you end up not *needing* to simulate a click to trigger the action. Since you're a Web developer, this should come fairly easily to you.

In this case, you'd want to refactor the toasts into a separate method (or multiple methods), and then call that both when the menu item is clicked and when you want to trigger it manually.

**Alternatively**, you could try taking the MenuItem returned by findViewById() and passing it to your handler there. But I have no idea if that'll work.

Comment: you can use the method performIdentifierAction

Comment: see @VadymVL answer, it is purely possible

Answer (score 10):

I would like to share my solution as well here. Instead of trying to click programmatically a menu item, I created a separate method for menu item click, and call it anywhere where I need to click menu item. `OnOptionsItemSelected` method looks as follows. As you can see I moved click logic to a separate method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        homeClicked();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void homeClicked(){
    ...
}
```

Now you can call `homeClicked` anytime you need to click menu item programmatically.

Comment: nice approach as we don't have native method

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's not the best way to do,

```
MenuItem item_your_choice;

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    item_your_choice = menu.findItem(R.id.item_your_choice);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case item_your_choice:
           //do whatever you want
            break;
        }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

just Call from any method

```
onOptionsItemSelected(item_you_choice);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Make global Menu

   ```
   public Menu mMenu;
   ```
2. Assign menu to mMenu while override onCreateOptionMenu

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
       this.mMenu = menu;
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```
3. Call event like this:

   ```
   if(mMenu != null) {
       MenuItem action = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_restart);

       if(action != null) {
           onOptionsItemSelected(action);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As per your example for menu item above :

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_restart" android:title="Restart"
        android:orderInCategory="1" />
```

use `callOnClick()` method :

```
((ActionMenuItemView)findViewById(R.id.action_restart)).callOnClick();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way, but here is how I did it.

**BottomNavigationItemView** has the method **callOnClick()**.

```
BottomNavigationItemView menuItem = findViewById(R.id.navigation_take_post);
menuItem.callOnClick();
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a standard method to do this - 
Create a new instance of `MenuItem` class and change the overridden method `getItemId()` to return the id of desired menu item and leave the rest unchanged.

```
MenuItem actionRestart = new MenuItem() {
                                             @Override
                                             public int getItemId() {
                                               return R.id.action_restart;
                                             }

                                             ...

                                           };
onOptionsItemSelected(actionRestart);
```

Comment: This will override all of the MenuItem's interface method, which makes your code messy